# Is it possible to keep margins from overflowing from their parent divs (especially body) without using padding?

Tags: html, css

I recently stumbled upon [this example](http://phrogz.net/CSS/valign_in_body/block.html) of using text with a limited width and a height equal to, or greater than, the containing HTML page. It all looked good until I checked the source...

There were two wrappers(!)  for the content. I realized that if I tried to change the padding of the inner wrapper, the `<h1>` inside both of them suddenly broke free and pushed both of them downward.

[image: padding:0 makes a mess.]

Is there any better workaround for this padding issue? With no padding, margins behave unpredictably. There's no way I know of to subvert this... not even `overflow:auto` would work without requiring another wrapper to keep the page's content from becoming its own narrow scrollable area.

**Edit:** **[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk1564dx/)** with a couple potential solutions.

- Solution 1: Requires an extra wrapper, which in turn requires its own extra padding. (Attempting to add padding into the `<body>` results in a bit of a mess.)
- Solution 2: Requires an enumeration of all the possible elements that could cause the content to balloon out: h1-h6, ul, ol, etc...

Comment: Add a fiddle and we can play with it to see what can be done...

Comment: ochi: consider it done.

Comment: I am trying to understand what the issue is; what exactly is the desired output?

Comment: @ochi: The desired output is to have the white section extend from the top of the page to the bottom, without any extraneous scrolling areas.

Comment: what about then setting the top-margin of `h1` to 0? 
i.e. `.wrapper h1{ margin-top:0; }`

Comment: @ochi: Well, per the fiddle, while it is *possible*, I wanted to leave out as much guesswork as possible. What if an h2 was used, for example? etc. See first answer-- my wish was somehow granted. I updated my fiddle with a working solution, thanks Oriol. http://jsfiddle.net/dk1564dx/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `h1` has some `top-margin`, which collapses to `.wrapper`.

You can avoid that inserting a pseudoelement between the top of `.wrapper` and the `h1`:

```css
.wrapper:before{
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also try `display: inline-block` (note it could produce additional space because of `line-height`), or `display: block; height: 1px`.

```css
html,body {
  margin:0; padding:0; height:100% 
}

html {
  background-color: gray;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: verdana, arial;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.wrapper:before{
    content: '';
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>README</h1>
  The top margin of the word README extends above the content of this text.
</div>
```

Comment: You can go sans `.wrapper` entirely and just apply that to `body:before`. Cool. The effect doesn't need extra padding *or* an extra wrapper to work! Example at http://jsfiddle.net/dk1564dx/2/